# Form doesn't resize properly in bootstrap when fully stacked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Example of code here: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9805/.

The form itself is:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Email</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Type in your email">
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that the form does not fill the body width when the window is re-sized to narrow widths, when all divs are stacked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `float: right` property. The column has 50% width and floats to right, leading to it "doesn't resize properly". It is fine above 768px, but below 768px the bootstrap's "mobile first" principle takes action and all the columns become `auto-width`. Above 768px width it had 50% width (your `col-sm-6`) but below it all collapses leading to ugly display.

You want a media query to make it look fine below 768px:

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9806/)

I added:

**HTML**

`col-sm-6 email-form` instead of `col-sm-6 pull-right`.

**CSS**

```
.email-form {
    float: right; /* Floats right when width > 768px */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .email-form {
        float: none; /* Doesn't float when width < 768px */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the form does still not fill the width as with the text divs when they are stacked and narrow. Can you amend?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">/*remove class pull-right*/
             <h3>2</h3>

            <form id="contactform" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Type in your email">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```